# How do I get the value of a variable in SCSS if only the variable name is given as a string?

Tags: css, string, sass, syntax

A variable is defined somewhere

```
$somevar: 'red';
```

Then I want to access this var but I only have the varname given as a string.

```
$varname: 'somevar';
```

What I want is something like:

```
$varvalue: getValueOfVar($varname);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$somevar: red;
```

and then

```
$varname: $somevar;
```

here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3y649dpq/)

Comment: Tanks for your answer, but i only have the NAME of the variable, in this case 'somevar' given. I want to resolve this name to a variable. In JavaScript like: eval('somevar');

JS:
somevar = 'Hello';
varname = 'somevar';
varvalue = eval(varname);